# Show that $x^*$ is minimizer of the function over $C$ if $x^*=\prod_C (x^*- \gamma \nabla f(x^*))$.

Tags: convex-optimization, projection

Assume $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable convex function and $C \subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ be a closed convex set, and $\gamma >0$. Consider the following problem

$$
\min_{x \in C}f(x)
$$

Show that $x^*$ is minimizer of the function over $C$ if $x^*=\prod_C (x^*- \gamma \nabla f(x^*))$.

To prove the above we need to use optimality condition as follows

$$
\langle\nabla f(x^*),x-x^* \rangle \geq0\,\,\, \forall x\in C
$$

Also, Variational Inequality for projection onto a closed convex set

$$
\langle x-\Pi_C (x),z-\Pi_C (x) \rangle \leq0\,\,\, \forall z\in C
$$

Answer (score 0):

Since $x^*$ is global minimizer we have 
$$
\langle\nabla f(x^*),x-x^* \rangle \geq0\,\,\, \forall x\in C
$$

Because $\gamma > 0$

$$
\langle -\gamma \nabla f(x^*),x-x^* \rangle \leq0\,\,\, \forall x\in C
$$

Add and subtract $x^*$ to get

$$
\langle \Big(x^*-\gamma \nabla f(x^*)\Big)-x^*,x-x^* \rangle \leq0\,\,\, \forall x\in C
$$

Compare with the Variational Inequality and note that $x^*-\gamma \nabla f(x^*) is \notin C$

$$
\langle x-\Pi_C (x),z-\Pi_C (x) \rangle \leq0\,\,\, \forall z\in C
$$

so $x^*$ should be $\Pi_C (x^*-\gamma \nabla f(x^*))$ to have VI to be true.

Comment: What is $\prod_C$?

Comment: It is projection onto set $C$.